# How to enable or disable all checkbox on List view with toggle button android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, toggle

hello everyone i need help in enable or disable list view items with toogle button.

in my case there a custom List view with List **item_name** and **checkobxs** .

here is the check box code i use the listview ebale or disable but not working .

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_campagin_lists, container, false);


        mydbhelper = new DBhelper(getContext());

        ContactsTypes = mydbhelper.getCaontactsTypesData();

        CheckBox03 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox03);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.campaign_list_view);

        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, ContactsTypes);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        CheckBox03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox03.setSelected(CheckBox03.isChecked());
                if (CheckBox03.isChecked()) 
                {
                    listView.setEnabled(false);
                }
           else {
                    listView.setEnabled(true);
                }
                                       }
                                                            });
        return view;
    }
```

Here is my **adapter**

```
 private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts> {
        private ArrayList<Contacts> contactsList;
        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Contacts> countryList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
            this.contactsList = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
            this.contactsList.addAll(countryList);
        }
        private class ViewHolder {
            RelativeLayout layout;
            TextView name;
            TextView count;
            CheckBox id;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.fragmentsrow, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_title);
                holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_count);
                holder.id = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
                holder.layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.android_list_view_tutorial_with_example);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
              } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            Contacts contact = contactsList.get(position);
            String name = contact.getName();
            String code = contact.getCode();
            boolean status = contact.isSelected();
                holder.name.setText(name);
                holder.count.setText(code);
                holder.id.setChecked(status);
                holder.id.setTag(contact);

            return convertView;
        }
```

and a toogle button above the list view.

i need to **Disable** the all checkboxs available in Listview when the toogle button is **ON**.

and same as when toggale button is **off** then **enable** the all Checkboxs in listview.

Comment: So basically, you want all listview checkboxes to be selected when you select that checkBox03 checkbox in Activity and vice versa. Right?

Comment: no  i want disable all items in listview i need when CheckBox03  is checked then make the all items disable in the list view.

Comment: I have added the new answer. Hope it helps in both achieving your requirement and optimizing the app at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Your Activity class:

```
CheckBox03.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                dataAdapter.setToggleStatus(b);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
            }
        });
```

Then in your adapter class, first add one global variable

`private boolean toggleState = true;`
`//make sure its true when you initialize it`

Then add this method in adapter class itself

```
public void setToggleStatus(boolean status){
   toggleState = status
}
```

Then in your `getView()` method just before `return convertView;` add this line

```
holder.id.setClickable(toggleState);
or
holder.id.setEnabled(toggleState);
```

Comment: did you try setting both clickable and enabled to toggleState??

Comment: code is working with holder.id.setEnabled(toggleState);   but problem is i have items with count ,Here is one another condition.

if count is 0 then checkboxes needs to disable .

but now when i use this way  disable is work gud but when im enable the boxes then it enable all checkboxes with 0 count also.

Comment: Good to know that your main task is now functional, little more code analysis and condition checks will solve your remaining problem too. I guess you can handle it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below instructions .........

> Create Static `boolean` variable inside your Activity Class.
>
> Attached that `boolean` with your Toggle button means set onclick
>   listener on toggle and change `boolean` variable.
>
> And use this `boolean` variable to enable and disable your Checkboxes.

Try this code ....

```
public static boolean flagToggle=false;//declare globally in Fragment....
```

Use this code instead of your `CLICK Listener` for change `flagToggle` value ...... `OnCheckedChangeListener` **is use for identify the checkBox boolean value (means provide you value that checkBox is checked or not )**

```
CheckBox03.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
          flagToggle=isChecked;
          dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
       }
   }
);
```

And use inside your adapter `getView()` method this code .........

```
if(FragmentName.flagToggle){
//here set your Views Enable
}else{
//here set your Views Disable
}
```

Feel free to ask if you stuck anywhere

enjoy coding...

Comment: i need to know to change the list view acording to the boolean value any example ...?

Comment: this the the way to do with toggle operations ...... Or post your code we can do something on it ...

Comment: Though this solution seems to work well, I oppose the use of static variable for 2 major reasons, efficiency and memory leaks. I prefer using a private variable witihin the adapter class whose value can be accessed and changed using getters and setters respectively.

Comment: JAVA lesson 101 : You can access private variable of other class using the public methods in that class to enforce data protection functionality of JAVA. No offense but, this is how you are ideally supposed to do.

Comment: i need  answer not  advise bro if you have answer of my problem then rply the answer other wise it's ok 

don't post unrelated comments

Comment: I have already posted the answer for you, Easy to implement and efficient for the app. And when it comes to advice, I hope you dont want to make you app lag by using inefficient shortcuts @sunny

Comment: im not getting your point and where is your post about question..?